# Why I am getting error: An operation is already in progress

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am getting next error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An operation is already in progress.

I can't understand it's reason. If I comment block that start-end all work fine. If no I am betting error. Any ideas?

```
     public void PGConnect()
    {
        List<UserData> uds = new List<UserData>();
        UserData ud;

        List<string> dblist = GetListDBsList();
        if (dblist.Contains(config.PGdbName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data Base exists: {0}", config.PGdbName);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data Base DO NOT exists: {0}", config.PGdbName);
            return;
        }

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=" + config.PGLogin + ";" +
           "Password=" + config.PGPass + ";Database=" + config.PGdbName + ";");

        //select datname from pg_database;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("PG Connected");
        }

        catch(SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        }

        //start
        string tablesListRequestSQL = @"SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'";
        NpgsqlCommand commandGetDBTables = new NpgsqlCommand(tablesListRequestSQL, conn);
        NpgsqlDataReader drGetDBTables = commandGetDBTables.ExecuteReader();
        //tr.Commit();
        while (drGetDBTables.Read())
        {
            existsInDBTables.Add(drGetDBTables[0].ToString());
        }

        foreach (string table in requireTablesList) // 
        {
            if (!existsInDBTables.Contains(table)) // if element from requireTablesList do not found -> DB have not simmilar Tables!
            {
                notFoundedTables.Add(table);
            }

        }

        if (notFoundedTables.Count != 0) // if not empty
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Next tables are marked as reqired for Sync, but can't be found in DataBase: ");

            foreach (var table in notFoundedTables)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(table);
            }
        }
        // end 


        Console.ReadKey();


         NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT city, state FROM cities", conn);


        try
        {

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader(); // VS show error here
            while (dr.Read())
            {
               // UserData ud = new UserData();
                ud.id = Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                ud.guid = (dr[1].ToString());
                ud.name = (dr[2].ToString());
                ud.userblob = (byte[])dr[3];
                uds.Add(ud);
                //File.WriteAllBytes("outputimg.jpg", ud.userblob);
                //Console.ReadKey();

            }

        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

---

Windows 7. VS2015. PG 9.5

---

How it's look like:
[image: my picture looks like this]

---

More pictures here:

http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/20/5717882d0b968.png

http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/20/57179041abaa4.png

http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/20/571790825648f.png

Comment: Is this on a raspberry pi? https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/826

Answer (score 8):

You should close previous DbDataReader before using the next one. Not closing it  causes this exception.

```
...    
if (notFoundedTables.Count != 0) // if not empty
{
    ...
}
// end 

/** IMPORTANT **/
/** Closing Data Reader **/
drGetDBTables.Close();

Console.ReadKey();

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT city, state FROM cities", conn);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not mixed sync and async calls at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  add 'Preload Reader=true' to  your connection  string.

According to this [Update Asp.net app to Npgsql 3 and removing Preload Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308718/update-asp-net-app-to-npgsql-3-and-removing-preload-reader) it may help you as it will allow the db driver to  free up the connection.

Comment: which version of Npgsql package you are using?

Comment: I am using Npgsql 3.0.5

Comment: This is what I get as an error `NotSupportedException: The PreloadReader parameter is no longer supported. Please see http://www.npgsql.org/doc/3.0/migration.html`